# How to get Vim to use a local spell-file in the current directory?

Tags: vim, spell-checking, spelling

I undestand Vim can do spell-check, and it can modify a spell-file inside ~/.vim to keep words flagged as good.

I'd like to keep a "local" spell-file in the same directory as a file I'm editing, so that if I'm in different directories editing different files, different spell-files would be used.

How would I set up Vim to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim's own help is usefull here:

```
:help spellfile
```

> ```
>     Name of the word list file where words are added for the 
>     zg and zw commands.  It must end in ".{encoding}.add". 
>     You need to include the path, otherwise the file is placed
>     in the current directory.
> ```

More detailed information:
http://thejakeharding.com/tutorial/2012/06/13/using-spell-check-in-vim.html
[Separate Vim spellfile for custom words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289012/separate-vim-spellfile-for-custom-words)

So:

```
:set spellfile=./en.utf-8.add
```

hth